# Tax return rejected, received a check

Tags: united-states, income-tax, loans, irs, turbotax

I filed my tax return in 2015 using TurboTax and received a check from both federal government and state.  I am currently applying for a loan.  When I downloaded the tax return statement (from TurboTax), I noticed it said "Your return has been rejected by the IRS".  Does this have any implications for my loan?  I wouldn't have thought I could get a check at all if my return was rejected.

Comment: This is a statement you received from TurboTax or from the IRS?

Comment: It says "Department of the Treasury—Internal Revenue Service
Income Tax Return for Single and
Joint Filers With No Dependents (99) 2015" At the top so I'm assuming IRS?  But I did download it from TurboTax.

Comment: I'd call TurboTax first, then the IRS.

Comment: How is the loan related to this?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer the loan is not related to the main question, but again Mocking is a first-time poster in this stack. I'd just remove the loan reference as it has no relation to the tax return issue that should be the main focus of the question.

Comment: @Mindwin - I don't take anything for granted. First time here, but anyone starting with 100+ rep is a member of at least one other stack. OP is welcome to answer my comment to clarify. His real question may very well be "I'm in the midst of a loan application, would this tax issue cause me trouble?" And that's a legit question.

Comment: Was this check you received your tax return?

Comment: When applying for a loan I was told I needed to submit two years of tax returns.  The checks I received were the tax returns.  I'm more concerned about the implications for the loan since I already received the 'cash' for the tax return.  But I'm also unsure of the implications of having it rejected and receiving checks.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't have the return rejected for some reason, fix the error, and transmit it again? So maybe the rejection is the first attempt, not the successful 2nd attempt? Also see https://www.irs.gov/individuals/get-transcript

Comment: @derobert I think that might have been the case.  I do remember having to resubmit, I'm just surprised it still showed up on the tax return.  The deadline for my loan application came up so I just submitted it as is and it seems fine.  If you submit your comment as an answer I will gladly accept it.